# Can someone explain how Text Formats work with CKEditor profiles? Very confused

Tags: wysiwyg

sorry if this is a silly question, but I'm stuck.  I'm trying to figure out the relationship between profiles configured in CKEditor and those configured in Config>Text Formats.

Some context:  In CK editor (Config > CKEditor), I set up three text editor formats:
- "Admin": Full editor for admin
- "Editor": Filtered-but-robust text editor for editors and bloggers
- "User": Filtered-but-VERY-simple text editor for everyone else.

In CKEditor, I don't see a way to assign these profile to different roles.

When I head over to Config > Text Formats, I DO see the ability to assign them to roles, and some configuration options.

Can someone explain the relationship (if any) or what I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you working on D6?

Answer (score 1):

The text formats have to do with how the text is being processed as you can have functions that process icon labels, tokens, video snippets, etc. Sometimes you don't want certain roles to have access to these properties.

For example, I wouldn't want to give a normal user access to add certain HTML tags or YouTube video tags, but I would want to give that access to a content editor.

With CKEditor, you can then assign a CKEditor profile with a certain set of buttons to each text format. For example, I would give a CKEditor profile with a lot of buttons and functionality to an admin or content editor, so I would pair that with the Full HTML text format, but I want to slim down the CKEditor profile for a regular user, so I would pair that with the Basic HTML text format (if I created one).

Comment: @rooby Can I clone a text format?

Comment: @Umair not that I'm aware of but I've never really looked for it.

Comment: @rooby I want to create a text format similar to plain_text text format

Comment: @Umair just create a new format and configure it similarly to the plain_text format.